# How do I show hemicontinuity of an operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $A: V \rightarrow V'$ with $V= H^1(\Omega)$ and $V' = H^{-1}(\Omega)$ be a nonlinear operator defined by
\begin{equation}
\langle Au, v \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1} = \int_{\Omega} \left(\dfrac{K \nabla u}{1+ K \vert \nabla u \vert} \nabla v + \lambda (u-f) v \right)dx  \thinspace \thinspace \text{    for all } u,v \in H^1(\Omega)
\end{equation}

where $\Omega$ is an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $K, \lambda >0$ and $f \in L^2(\Omega)$.

Now I want to show that this operator is hemicontinuous and by definition a operator $A: V \rightarrow V'$ is hemicontinuous if for all $u,v,w \in V$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ the map $\theta \rightarrow \langle A(u + \theta v), w \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1}$ is continuous.

I don't exactly know how to show hemicontinuity.
My idea ist to show that $\lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \langle A (u + \theta v),w \rangle = \langle Au,w\rangle$. Is my approach correct and if yes, can someone help me with the details of the proof?